# Flutter XCode build module 'flutter_ffmpeg' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, flutter-ios-build

I'm facing an error in my flutter project during XCode's build. Build is working fine in android's case and when I run following command

```
flutter build ios --release --no-codesign
```

If I remove `--no-codesign`, I get following error

```
Error (Xcode): Target release_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to codesign
project-directory/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Flutter with identity
2B3A000417513B63E3DB519A0AF3919A4DE61267.


Encountered error while building for device.
```

If I use XCode to build project, I get following error in file `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m`

```
Module 'flutter_ffmpeg' not found
```

I have tried following things

1. Clean Project Build from XCode
2. iOS target Platform is same in Xcode Info and Podfile (iOS 11.0)
3. Removed Podfile.lock and Pods directory and regenerated it
4. Tried following commands

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod deintegrate 
pod install
```

Nothing seems to work. I have remote access to Mac instance and can only run simulator. What am I doing wrong here?